# How do I create an if statement in Sass that locates a child?

Tags: css, sass

With the code below, I want to apply the h2 value to every "section" except the first one.

```
body > section {
  h2 {
      color: white;
  }
}
```

Here's a messy idea of what I'm attempting to do. If there a way to use the if statement or do I need to run a for loop instead?

```
body > section {
  $first-child == body > section:first-child;

  @if $first-child != true {
    h2 {
      color: white;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you  mean by "apply the h2 value"?

Comment: Maybe I mis-worded. "h2" has a property:value of color:white. I want to apply that to all sections except the first one.

Comment: Sass doesn't know anything about your document, it only compiles to CSS.

Comment: Fundamentally CSS is a declarative language, not an imperative one. You don't write how to do something, you wrote what you want. There are no if statements. The closest thing to an if statement is a selector which matches some things and not others. If you want to write styling logic in procedural fashion, write it in JavaScript.

Comment: My question was specifically for Sass, which allows for if statements.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for browser versions that support CSS3:

```
body > section:not(:first-child) h2 {
    color: white;
}
```

If you need to support older browsers and your headings have a specific color, you can use:

```
body > section h2 {
    color: white;
}
body > section:fist-child {
    color: whatever your h2 color is normally;
}
```